# how to share animated gif on facebook

Tags: facebook

i'm going to create facebook app using javascript sdk.i want to create app which shroud be able to post animated gif .my idea arise after see this app and https://www.facebook.com/khalil.shr/app_212097992149339. it  work 100 percent .

and another best example is https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=471334666225107&set=p.471334666225107&type=1  take a look this picture animated without clicking on it.i can't guess how it work ..i want a complete guide about that ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no API which allows animated GIFs to be uploaded to Facebook - any you see on Facebook were uploaded while there was a bug in the image validation code and are only visible because the images were not retroactively removed

Comment: files already in Facebook's CDN can be reshared, new files shouldn't be uploadable - and i'm not going to like that page to confirm how they're doing it

Comment: but i uplord new animated gif yersterday using that app

Comment: You most likely shared an existing image using that app - if you find a way to upload new animated GIFs please report it via the whitehat program: https://www.facebook.com/whitehat

Comment: yes i did yesterday .animated gif was created by me using photoshop cs6 .

Comment: This answer is now out of date, and Facebook's UI allows GIF uploads

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload an animated GIF to Facebook. There are however some ways to outsmart the system. For example, the 3 ways mentioned in [Guide to Animated Gifs for Facebook](http://facebook.about.com/od/Advanced/ss/Guide-To-Animated-Gifs-For-Facebook.htm). It says:

> If you try to upload a GIF to Facebook, a still image of the first
>   frame will appear. However, there are three ways to try and outsmart
>   the system.
>
> - Make a Youtube video look like a GIF.
> - Use a third party app on    Facebook like Animated Picture. For this    app, you do not use your own    files. There are hundreds
>     sorted out    in different categories to    choose from.
> - Post a link to the GIF. Yes, the still image will show    up, but a    description will accompany it. Yes, it may take more time,    but
>     your friends will be curious as to what it entails.
>
> But, if the GIF you want to upload is not a moving picture, it should
>   work just fine. If you have a GIF image that is a nonmoving image, you
>   should have no problem uploading it to Facebook. According to the
>   Facebook Developers page, GIFs are one of many file types allowed for
>   uploading to the platform. Other supported image file types include
>   JPG, PNG, PSD, TIFF, JP2, IFF, WBMP and XBM images.

Similarly, you can find many other workarounds to this on the internet.

Comment: One app that might work (if you have iPhone) is GifShare which converts your GIF into a Video. http://bit.ly/gifshare

Answer (score 2):

there was a bug back in 2012 which allowed user to upload an animated .gif by renaming it to .jpg and then upload it as an image. This has been fixed , although you can still see the gifs that were uploaded before the fix.

NB: check uploaded date of all animated images in facebook, all of them are uploaded on or before year 2012

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Facebook finally enabled the GIF support!

You can upload gif image to some 3rd party website (Gipfy or something else) and then upload this link to facebook - then it'll be displayed as animated GIF!

http://techcrunch.com/2015/05/29/facebook-confirms-it-will-officially-support-gifs/#.pfn8nn:CJC4

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to publish a GIF through the Graph API, please see an example call below:

```
curl \
-X POST \
"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.8/{page-id}/videos"  \
-F "access_token=<sanitized>" \
-F "source=fluffy_cat.gif" \
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now post an animated Gif on facebook by posting it as a video. If you post it as a photo it will not be animate-able and will display the first frame only.

To post an animated gif from URL use this Graph API call:

```
POST /me/videos
access_token=<access token with "publish_actions" permission>
file_url=<url to file>
```

Alternatively you can replace `me` with another user or page identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share an animated gif on Facebook, is to

1. Upload the GIF to an image hosting site that allows animated gifs, such as http://imgur.com or http://photobucket.com then
2. Get the direct URL to the image from that site
3. Post the URL to the GIF on Facebook
4. Remove the image preview, as that will be a still image, and people won't realise its an animated gif if they see a still image preview. Add text to the image's description that it is an animated GIF, and that they need to click the link to see the animation.

**Pro Tip**: If you want to be able to view animated GIFs directly on Facebook, without having to click the GIF links as mentioned in the method above. You can use a browser extension such as FB Purity : http://fbpurity.com as it has an option called "View Animated Gifs". When this option is turned on, whenever the extension sees a link to an animated GIF on the Facebook site, it automatically converts it to a fully working and moving Animated GIF, so you don't even need to click the link to see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to convert the animated Gif into a video file then upload that, as Facebook now autoplays Video files, just like animated gifs. One way to convert an animated GIF to a video file is to use the free, open source **Virtual Dub** software. Get Virtual Dub here http://www.virtualdub.org

Open your **.gif** as a video file in Virtual Dub... then save as **.avi** then upload the new file to Facebook.

Though you can search google for other methods of converting animated gifs to video files if you dont want to use Virtual Dub.

There are also some other alternative methods listed here:
https://superuser.com/questions/5730/how-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-a-youtube-friendly-video-format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from your own site you must have verified (green lock icon)secure layer socket SSL installed certificates. Then just go to Facebook debug and add the link. EASY!